# Insert a button and load a second view programmatically using Swift

Tags: ios, uibutton, swift

I want to, programmatically, add a button to a view and then when the user press this button a second view called "Giraanam" is loaded. I managed to write the code to display the button, but I cannot discover how to make it load the second view... Can anyone please help me?

The code I tried so far is:

```
let button = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
button.frame = CGRectMake(20, 25, 34, 34)
button.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named:"Back_Resultados.png"),forState: UIControlState.Normal)
button.addTarget(self, action: "Giraanam",  forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
self.addSubview(button)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement function `Giraanam` to create a new view and add to another view. Example:

```
func Giraanam() {

   let newView = UIView()

// customise your view

   self.view.addSubview(newView)
}
```